# C# Registry.getValue function return null even though the value exist

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I am making program like window regedit.

I use C# to fetch registry key and value.

I have problem to get some registry value. when I get value of HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Arbiters\AlocationOrder .

[image]

There is Root value. value type is REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENT_LIST. when I get this value using RegistryKey.getValue in c#, it returns null.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security;

namespace GetRegistryList
{
    class RegData
    {
        public string name { get; set; }            
        public string fullPath { get; set; }         
        public string regRoot { get; set; }         

        public Boolean hasFolder { get; set; }      

        public List<RegValue> values { get; set; }  



        public RegData()
        {
            this.values = new List<RegValue>();

        }



        public void setRegDataValue(string[] args, RegData regData)
        {

            string rootString = "";
            string fullPath = "";
            if (args.Length > 1)
            {
                rootString = args[0];
                fullPath = args[1];
            }




            **//HKLM   fullPath = SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Arbiters\AllocationOrder\
            RegistryKey rootKey = getRootKey(rootString).OpenSubKey(fullPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree, RegistryRights.ReadKey);**      
            string[] splitResult;
            if (fullPath == "\\")
            {
                regData.name = fullPath;
            }
            else
            {
                splitResult = fullPath.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                regData.name = splitResult[splitResult.Length - 1];
            }

            regData.fullPath = fullPath;
            regData.regRoot = rootString;
            regData.hasFolder = rootKey.SubKeyCount > 0 ? true : false;


            //this.regData.values = 


            string[] valueNames = rootKey.GetValueNames();

            foreach (var name in valueNames)
            {
                //val

                RegistryValueKind valuekind = rootKey.GetValueKind(name);   

                RegValue tempReg;
                Object a = rootKey.GetValue(name);
                //Console.WriteLine();

                switch (valuekind)
                {


                    case RegistryValueKind.Binary:               
                        System.Byte[] arr = (System.Byte[])rootKey.GetValue(name);
                        tempReg = new RegValue(name, "Binary", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arr));
                        break;
                    case RegistryValueKind.DWord:                  
                        tempReg = new RegValue(name, "DWord", rootKey.GetValue(name).ToString());
                        break;
                    case RegistryValueKind.ExpandString:
                        tempReg = new RegValue(name, "ExpandString", rootKey.GetValue(name).ToString());
                        break;
                    case RegistryValueKind.QWord:                       
                        tempReg = new RegValue(name, "QWord", rootKey.GetValue(name).ToString());
                        break;
                    case RegistryValueKind.String:                      
                        tempReg = new RegValue(name, "String", rootKey.GetValue(name).ToString());
                        break;
                    case RegistryValueKind.MultiString:
                        string str = "";
                        foreach (var v in (System.String[])rootKey.GetValue(name))
                        {
                            str += v + System.Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                        tempReg = new RegValue(name, "MultiString", str);
                        break;
                    case RegistryValueKind.None:                    
                        tempReg = new RegValue(name, "None", rootKey.GetValue(name).ToString());
                        break;
                    **case RegistryValueKind.Unknown:     // value type is unkown and rootKey.getValue(name) is null.**
                        tempReg = new RegValue(name, "Unknown", rootKey.GetValue(name) as string);
                        break;
                    default:
                        tempReg = new RegValue(name, "NoDefine", rootKey.GetValue(name).ToString());
                        break;


                }
                regData.values.Add(tempReg);


            }//foreach

        }



        public RegistryKey getRootKey(string rootString)
        {

            switch (rootString)
            {
                case "HKCR":
                    return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, RegistryView.Registry64);
                case "HKCU":
                    return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
                case "HKLM":
                    return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
                case "HKUS":
                    return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.Users, RegistryView.Registry64);
                case "HKCC":
                    return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentConfig, RegistryView.Registry64);
                case "HKDD":
                    return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.DynData, RegistryView.Registry64);
                case "HKPD":
                    return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.PerformanceData, RegistryView.Registry64);
                default:
                    return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, RegistryView.Registry64);
                    break;


            }


        }
    }

    public class RegValue
    {

        public string valueName { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public System.Byte[] binaryValue;


        public RegValue(string valueName, string type, string stringValue)
        {
            this.valueName = valueName;
            this.type = type;
            this.stringValue = stringValue;
        }
        public RegValue(string valueName, string type, System.Byte[] binaryValue)
        {
            this.valueName = valueName;
            this.type = type;
            this.binaryValue = binaryValue;
        }


    }

}
```

this is part of my code to get registry value. It can get valuenames in 
            string[] valueNames = rootKey.GetValueNames();
but when I try to get value of registry they return null and value type is unknown.

How can I get the value of registry like this using c#?

Comment: it is probably due to wrong environment variable target. Maybe this key only exist for specific user not whole machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
 Dim SettingType = regSubKey.GetValueKind(SettingName)
    If SettingType = RegistryValueKind.Binary Then
                    type = "REG_BINARY"
                    Dim value = regSubKey.GetValue(SettingName)
                    SettingValue = BitConverter.ToString(value)
    end if
```